# Draw custom ellipse in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, shapes

In `System.Drawing` and `System.Drawing.Drawing2D`, I can only draw horizontal or vertical shape. Now i want to draw custom shape.

Given the coordinate of points A, B, C, D. I want to draw an ellipse like the blue one in the picture.
[image]

Comment: So you will have to do a little, rather basic math. Then you need to do a TranslateTransform, RotateTransform and  finally the DrawEllispse. Afterwards probably a ResetTransform.

Comment: read about [RotateTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below is taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private void RotateTransformAngle(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Set world transform of graphics object to translate.
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(100.0F, 0.0F);

    // Then to rotate, prepending rotation matrix.
    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(30.0F);

    // Draw rotated, translated ellipse to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Blue, 3), 0, 0, 200, 80);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution involves:

- Calculating the center
- using `Graphics.TranslateTransform` to move the center to the origin
- Calculating the `Size` and the `Location` of the bounding `Rectangle`
- using `Graphics.RotateTransform` to rotate the canvas
- Drawing the ellipse with `Graphics.DrawEllipse`
- Resetting the `Graphcis` object

This does take a little `Math` but will produce real and fine ellipses..

For fun you also may want to play with a cheap, fake solution: I uses the `DrawClosedCurve` method with a tension.

To test I added a `TrackBar` set with a `Maximum` of `100`.

Values of around 80, i.e. `Tensions` of around `0.8f` create pretty nice ellipsoids:

[image]

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    List<Point> points1 = new List<Point>()
    { new Point(300, 100), new Point(500, 300), new Point(400, 500), new Point(200, 300) };

    List<Point> points2 = new List<Point>() 
    { new Point(100, 100), new Point(500, 100), new Point(500, 400), new Point(100, 400) };

    e.Graphics.DrawClosedCurve(Pens.Red, points1.ToArray(), 
        (float)(trackBar1.Value / 100f), System.Drawing.Drawing2D.FillMode.Alternate);

    e.Graphics.DrawClosedCurve(Pens.Blue, points2.ToArray(), 
        (float)(trackBar1.Value / 100f), System.Drawing.Drawing2D.FillMode.Alternate);
}
```